# RuntimeError: LookupError: IndexError: multi_usrp: RX channel 1 out of range for configured RX frontends - GNU Radio

Tags: python, gnu, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, usrp

I am trying to receive a signal on two RX channels using the USRP B205mini. I am trying achieve this using GNU Radio. However, after running the code, I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: LookupError: IndexError: multi_usrp: RX channel 1 out of range for configured RX frontends

I have tried to look on the internet, but I have not found a proper solution yet.

I tried to test the two channels that I am using - RX2 and TX/RX using two UHD USRP Source blocks (independently of each other), and they work.

When I try to test them together, using a single UHD USRP block, I get the following error: "RuntimeError: LookupError: IndexError: multi_usrp: RX channel 1 out of range for configured RX frontends - GNU Radio".

[This is what I am trying to do when I get the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peQYi.png)

[Block Specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL0j1.png)

[Block Specification 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU2jU.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The B205-mini only has a single RX channel.

So, trying to get a second channel *must* fail.

Comment: The one that I am using has 2 RX (RX1 and RX2) channels and a TX/RX channel.
I am using RX2 and the TX/RX ones.

Comment: it does not. You can switch the one RX channel either to "TX/RX" or to "RX2", but it's only one channel. The AD9364 on the B205mini only has one channel. Your B205mini-i should have one "TX/RX", one "RX2", and one "REF". If you have a different configuration, please do reach out to support@ettus.com (disclaimer: I'm affiliated with Ettus support)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34381781)

Comment: There's no link in the answer. This wasn't high-quality review, @B25Dec. But I guess you intend to say: please add a reference to your answer? But the reference lies literally, as piece of hardware in front of the asker. Small PCB, three SMA connectors on one side, one labeled REF, one labeled RX/TX, and one labeled RX2. I'll go as far as saying I'm an authority on that device.

Comment: Marcus you are right, thank you for clarifying this to me.

Comment: @Marcus Müller as a reviewer it was downvoted already before me, for me, it was looking like a bad answer. But other community contributors have already voted as "Looks OK". I tried finding how to reverse my review but at the moment I didn't find any way. Hope this is good now. We are just doing it for the betterment of the community.

Comment: @B25Dec no worries! It's just that you literally clicked on a review comment that says "link-only answers …", and there's no link in the answer, so that's why I said it was a low-quality review. Such things happen! Don't worry too much :)